# Create a predicate matching 2 lists

Tags: content-search

I have a multilist field (Product Category).
I am getting a list of Product Category from the session.
How can i write a predicate to filter all those items which has one common category without custom field

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through categories from the session and check if categories from the product contain any of them:

```
var query = PredicateBuilder.And<ProductSearchItem>();

if (categories.Any())
{
    var categoryExpression = PredicateBuilder.False<ProductSearchItem>();

    foreach (var category in categories)
    {
        categoryExpression = categoryExpression.Or(p => p.Categories.Contains(category));
    }

    query = query.And(categoryExpression);
}
```

Comment: foreach (var category in categories) { var normalizedID = Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.IdHelper.NormalizeGuid(category.ID); predicate = predicate.Or(x => x["categotytype_sm"].ToString().Contains(normalizedID.ToString())); }                             I did this but its not coming seems while comparing with multilist getting no value